# Show style even that css file is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I started to learn mvc, something weird happens, I have `index.cshtml` and inside of it I have:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

where `Index.css` is empty file, even that this css file is empty the page gets style, and if I comments the line like:

```
 @*<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
```

then there is no style to the page

Comment: Your question is clear but you will need to provide more detail, 
but first if you are using visual studio, check ~AppStart/BundleConfig.cs and you will see all the css files bundled there also check your Layout.cshtml for any @RenderSection("css", required: false).
to be sure you don't have css files included.
Alternatively load your page in Chrome, inspect and go to Sources Tab, you will see all the file loaded for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've your `Index.css` stored in some different location, it could be not visible in Solution Explorer. Try switching to `Folder View` and search for that css file.

Also it might be stored in bin/obj folder. In that case you can try `git clean -fxd`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some stylesheets or bundles are referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

The `_Layout.cshtml` is per default the layout for all views so the styles and scripts referenced in it will effect your `index.cshtml` as well.